# Ionic - Disable swiping on individual ion-items programmatically

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ion-list that contains ion-items. `can-swipe` is set to `true` on the individual items. I toggled it to `false` to try to disable swiping on the items, but this did not disable swiping (this was my first test to see if I could hook up a condition to the `can-swipe` attribute).

How would I disable certain items, since `can-swipe="false"` is not doing the trick?

```
<ion-list show-reorder="data.showReorder">
    <ion-item ng-repeat="i in items track by $index" class="item item-remove-animate"
        can-swipe="true" ng-click="manageOption($index);">
        <b>{{i.Name}}</b>
    <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="deleteOption($index);">
        Delete
    </ion-option-button>
    <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon" on-reorder="moveOption(o, $fromIndex, $toIndex)"></ion-reorder-button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 6):

I needed this for my app, and I was able to use CSS classes to override the transformation on the `item-content` element that is dynamically added as a child to `ion-item`.

I have the following in my template:

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="report in dashboardReports" ng-class="isSwipeable(report.id)">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <ion-option-button ng-click="itemButton(report.id)">
</ion-item>
```

Then in my controller I have this:

```
$scope.lockedItems = []

$scope.itemButton = function(id) {
  $scope.lockedItems.append(id)
}

$scope.isSwipeable = function (id) {
  if ($scope.lockedItems.indexOf(id) !== -1) {
    return 'swipe-disabled';
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

Then in my CSS, I override the swipe animation like so:

```
.swipe-disabled div.item-content {
    -webket-transition: none !important;
    -webket-transform: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
}
```

I have a feeling this is kind of hacky, but Eder's solution did not work for me and Ion does not support this yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a

```
ng-show="showButton(i)"
```

On your ion-option-button or reorder.
On your scope, keep the logic:

```
$scope.showButton(item)
{
  return item.show; //Or whatever logic you want to have. 
}
```

Hope it works! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think Wrapping the `ion-option-button`  in a `div` with a `ng-if` directive will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

`can-swipe="false"` will not work on `ion-item` only `ion-list`.

But you can try:

```
var functions = angular.module('yourmodule', []);
functions.directive('dontSwipeMe', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr) { 
            element.on("dragstart", function(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();      
            });
        }
    };
});
<ion-item dontSwipeMe> </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Self sufficient `can-swipe` directive for `ion-item`. It does not have any dependency on external resources:

```
.directive('canSwipe', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require:  '^ionItem',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, itemCtrl) {

      if(attr.canSwipe !== null && attr.canSwipe.length > 0 && 
         typeof(!!attr.canSwipe) === "boolean") {
        scope.$watch('!!(' + attr.canSwipe + ')', function(value) {
          canSwipe(value);
        });
      }

      canSwipe(attr.canSwipe === 'true');

      function canSwipe(can) {
        if (!itemCtrl.optionsContainer) {
          return;
        }
        // Class item-options is the flag for ionic.views.ListView whether 
        // item can be swiped (dragged):
        //    if (item && item.querySelector('.item-options')) { do drag ...}
        itemCtrl.optionsContainer.toggleClass('item-options', can);
        // Hide options button container.
        itemCtrl.optionsContainer.toggleClass('ng-hide', !can);
      } // canSwipe

    } // link
  }; // return
}) // canSwipe directive
```

See [live can-swipe example on Codepen](http://codepen.io/MichalFoksa/pen/BLNQYw?editors=1010).

[image]

Tested with `Ionic 1.3.1`.

**Links:**

[can-swipe](https://github.com/MichalFoksa/ionic-gizmos/tree/master/can-swipe) directive on Github.